# Ruby on Rails - Regular expression for error routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I define a routes match any things exclude string ( like 'websocket' )?

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it clearly shown OP didn't even look at Rails Guides. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints

Comment: Does the string consist of that word only, or *includes* that word beside other characters?

Comment: @MichalSzyndel Even if he did look at that guide, it's still difficult to construct the constraint regex.

Comment: Sorry, that is hard here? Everything needed is linked guide and a BASIC knowledge of regexp, which also takes 5 seconds to google.

Comment: @TamerShlash: I want it matches all pattern except'/websocket'. I tried to read rails document but it's still hard to implement. In regex forum, i implemented: #match '^((?!websocket).)*$' => "errors#show", :code => 500, :via => [:get]. It doesn't work :(

Comment: @PhuongTT I couldn't figure it out either, does it harm to add that logic in the controller?

Comment: @TamerShlash: I just want to add it to end of routes.rb. I want everytime user try to enter invalid path from address bar browser, just redirect them to 404 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, it sounds like you want to match `/websocket` to a specific action and everything else to an 404 error page.

Utilizing the fact that routes are matched in the order they are defined in `routes.rb`, this is a good approach to do it:

```
match '/websocket' => 'controller#action'
match '/:slug' => "errors#show", :code => 404, :via => [:get]
```

When a request `/string` comes, the routing subsystem will first try to match it to the first line, and if `string` is equal to `websocket` then the match is successful and no more routes will be matched.

If `string` is not `websocket` on the other hand, then it will match the second line.

Comment: I used https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails. It defined websocket routes in events.rb file. And '/websocket' is default add to listen client event. I think i got confused to implement this. :(.

Comment: @PhuongTT you have to make it clear that you're asking something related to that gem instead of posting a single-line question.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have just read this gem code. It is good opportunity to learn more. I'm have learnt ruby for a month :D.